# I get ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (1000,) and requested shape (1000,1)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

```
# In order to use the 3D plot, the objects should have a certain shape, so we reshape the targets.
# The proper method to use is reshape and takes as arguments the dimensions in which we want to fit the object.
targets = targets.reshape(observations,)

# Plotting according to the conventional matplotlib.pyplot syntax

# Declare the figure
fig = plt.figure()

# A method allowing us to create the 3D plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Choose the axes.
ax.plot(xs, zs, targets)

# Set labels
ax.set_xlabel('xs')
ax.set_ylabel('zs')
ax.set_zlabel('Targets')

# You can fiddle with the azim parameter to plot the data from different angles. Just change the value of azim=100
# to azim = 0 ; azim = 200, or whatever. Check and see what happens.
ax.view_init(azim=100)

# So far we were just describing the plot. This method actually shows the plot. 
plt.show()

# We reshape the targets back to the shape that they were in before plotting.
# This reshaping is a side-effect of the 3D plot. Sorry for that.
targets = targets.reshape(observations,1)
```

the shape of xs and zs is (1000,1)
the shape of targets is (1000,) even if keep its shape as (1000,1) I get a new error like this
AttributeError: 'Line3D' object has no attribute '_verts3d'

Comment: Try this `targets = targets.reshape(-1, 1)` before `ax.plot(xs, zs, targets)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: actually i found the mistake. It is running fine. I had to just reshape ax and zx into single dimension for the plot to work. That's it. Anyway thanks for you help!!